# Google Visualization Column Chart specify Target line as Certainty role

Tags: json, charts, logic, google-visualization, google-datatable

When i put this below code i came with on visualization playground i get the Goal/Target line, but i want it to be dashed/dotted which requires certainty role as specified in the docs. Can anyone enlighten me how to do it with a array input to Google Datatable, or Datatable json string format

**Code**

```
function drawVisualization() {

  // Create and populate the data table.
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Red', 'Yellow', 'Green','Target'],
    ['2003',  20,   0,      0,80],
    ['2004',  0,   55,      0,80],
    ['2005',  0,   0,       80,80],
    ['2005',  0,   0,      85,80]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data,
           {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
            width:600, height:400,
            hAxis: {title: "Year"},
            legend:'none',
            colors:['red','yellow','green'],
            //isStacked: true,
            series:{
              3:{type:'steppedArea',areaOpacity:0}
            }
            //interpolateNulls: true
           }
      );
}​
```

**Update**

I got it to this level below, with the code but how do i make the line stretch graph width
[image: Indicator Arrow & Description to extend dashed line]

```
function drawVisualization() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Month'); // Implicit domain label col.
data.addColumn('number', 'Sales'); // Implicit series 1 data col.
data.addColumn({type:'number'});  // interval role col.
data.addColumn({type:'number'});  // interval role col.
data.addColumn({type:'number'});  // interval role col.
data.addColumn({type:'boolean',role:'certainty'}); // certainty col.
data.addRows([
    ['Red',20,  0,0,  80,true],
    ['Yellow',  0, 55, 0,  80,false],
    ['Green',  0,  0,  85,  80,false]
]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data,
           {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
            width:600, height:400,
            hAxis: {title: "Year"},
            legend:'none',
            colors:['red','yellow','green'],
            //isStacked: true,
            series:{
              3:{type:'line',areaOpacity:0}
            }
            //interpolateNulls: true
           }
      );
}​
```

**PlayGround:**

https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#column_chart

**Roles Docs:**

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles

1. So what is the right JSON format for dashed lines?
2. Is there any, i mean anyway i can display a arrow indicator at the right corner of the Target line to visually indicate the Goal?

Comment: With a discrete (string-based) x-axis, you can't get the dashed line to extend to the edges of the chart.

Comment: @asgallant So what will work in this situation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating empty columns at the beginning and end of your chart, and then setting the view window to be within the range that you actually want. The code below achieves this:

```
    function drawVisualization() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Month'); // Implicit domain label col.
      data.addColumn('number', 'Sales'); // Implicit series 1 data col.
      data.addColumn({type:'number'});  // interval role col.
      data.addColumn({type:'number'});  // interval role col.
      data.addColumn({type:'number'});  // interval role col.
      data.addColumn({type:'boolean',role:'certainty'}); // certainty col.
      data.addRows([
        ['', null, null, null, 80, false],
        ['Red',20,  0,0,  80,true],
        ['Yellow',  0, 55, 0,  80,false],
        ['Green',  0,  0,  85,  80,false],
        ['', null, null, null, 80, true]
      ]);

      // Create and draw the visualization.
      new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
        draw(data,
             {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
              width:600, height:400,
              hAxis: {title: "Year"},
              legend:'none',
              colors:['red','yellow','green'],
              //isStacked: true,
              series:{
                3:{type:'line',areaOpacity:0}
              },
              hAxis: {
                viewWindow: {
                  min: 1,
                  max: 4
                }
              }

              //interpolateNulls: true
             }
            );
    }
    ​
```

Comment: I didn't know you could use the hAxis.viewWindow option for discrete axes.  Do the min/max refer to the row indices in this case?

Comment: @SergeyG Awesomesness +!